# Exact same model in tf.keras and Pytorch yeilding very different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a modified version of the AlexNet CNN. I have an array of (1000,800,600,1) image data, and another (1000,4) array of one-hot encoded labels. The loss function and optimizer is identical.

Passing the data through the keras model for 8 epochs yields accuracies and losses as follows, where each element of the list is an epoch:
`Loss: [0.8518, 0.4651, 0.4593, 0.3215, 0.2821, 0.2545, 0.1822, 0.1479]`
`Accuracy: [0.7450, 0.8320, 0.8220, 0.8780, 0.8940, 0.8990, 0.9310, 0.9450]`

Passing the same exact data through pytorch yields the following. Running for more epochs does not help, it stays stuck at ~77% accuracy:
`Loss: [1.3958, 1.3857, 1.3707, 1.3423, 1.2977, 1.2504, 1.2005, 1.1429]`
`Accuracy: [19.80%, 24.40%, 35.60%, 55.60%, 72.00%, 75.10%, 76.40%, 76.90%]`

Why could this be happening? The models and data are exactly the same. The models for both are given below.

tf.keras:

```
def createModel(width, height, lr, num_outputs=4):
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Conv2D(96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(width,height,1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

  model.add(Conv2D(256, 5, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

  model.add(Flatten())
  
  model.add(Dense(4096,activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(4096,activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(num_outputs,activation='softmax'))

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr, momentum=0.9)
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

kerasmodel=createModel(HEIGHT,WIDTH,LR,num_outputs=4)
```

PyTorch:

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs=4):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 96, kernel_size=11, stride=4)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        self.norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(96,affine=False)
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(96, 256, kernel_size=5)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        self.norm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256,affine=False)
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 9, 4096)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4096, num_outputs)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.norm1(x)
        
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.norm2(x)

        x = self.flatten(x)
        
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        
        x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), dim=1)

        
        return x

torchmodel = AlexNet(num_outputs=4)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(torchmodel.parameters(), lr=LR, momentum=0.9)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Comment: If your model has the same architecture. It might come from the initialization of the neural networks. Hence starting the optimization loop from different points in the parameter space.